# Constant speed parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I am studying the book "Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature" by Lee. The following statement is from that book.

Let $S^n$ be the sphere of radius $1.$ The Geodesics of $S^n$ are precisely the great circles with constant speed parametrization.

I want to know what he means by ``constant speed parametrization" ad how to obtain such a parametrization when one is already given with a parametrization.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gamma:I\to R^n$ is a curve, then its derivative $\gamma':I\to R^n$ is the velocity vector and its modulus is the so-called *speed*. So the parameterization $\gamma$ has constant speed if $|\gamma'(t)|=v$ for some positive constant $v>0$.

Any *regular* curve can be reparameterized to have unit speed. It does not make sense to write down the details here as this is something that you can find in the first chapter of every book on classical differential geometry. For example, in Do Carmo book.

Comment: the last sentence is inappropriate and should be deleted.

Comment: Was a suggestion. But if this is the policy I remove it :-)

Comment: The tone of the second paragraph could also be more respectful. You should simply say that the details can be found in .... But cite both the author *and* the title. Do Carmo has written more than one book.

Comment: The second paragraph is OK.

Comment: Could you say which Do Carmo book you're referring to?